# Screen truecolor Ubuntu 18.04 broke

Tags: ncurses, gnu-screen, terminfo, termcap

One of the few pieces of software that I compile myself is screen. I've found it tends to support some modern features of terminals better than the version in the repositories. I've been doing this for some time now without too much of an issue. However, on upgrade to 18.04, (true)colors seem to have broken.

I run this bit of code to print a rainbow, which still works in a bare konsole:

```
awk 'BEGIN{                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    s="/\\/\\/\\/\\/\\"; s=s s s s s s s s;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    for (colnum = 0; colnum<77; colnum++) {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
        r = 255-(colnum*255/76);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
        g = (colnum*510/76);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
        b = (colnum*255/76);
        if (g>255) g = 510-g;
        printf "\033[48;2;%d;%d;%dm", r,g,b;
        printf "\033[38;2;%d;%d;%dm", 255-r,255-g,255-b;
        printf "%s\033[0m", substr(s,colnum+1,1);
    }
    printf "\n";
}'
```

However, when I start screen, the colors are off. It doesn't appear to have fallen back to 256 colors, but rather, the color values are wrong.

I saw this behavior before any recompilation of screen. After seeing the issue, I recompiled and even nuked my git repo and re-cloned and recompiled to try to get things working, to no avail.

Thoughts on where this has gone wrong? I'm not even sure which library might be responsible for this, or how it might work with konsole but not screen.

The good colors look like this:
[image: good colors]

The bad colors look like this:
[image]

Comment: Do you use released versions of GNU Screen, the git master branch or the screen-v4 branch when you compile screen? (Out of curiosity, not related to your issue. :-)

Comment: Well, actually, true color support seems only to be in the git master branch, so I assume you're using that one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Someone reminded me about this: it is a bug in screen (see [source-repo](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/screen.git/commit/?id=3ccd012b20857869821c9529272cd095ccbc9c36)):

```
tputs(tparm("\E[48;2;%d;%d;%dm", _r, _g, _b), 1, DoAddChar);
```

The problem is that it is using [**`tparm`**](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_terminfo.3x.html#h3-Formatting-Output) to process **3** parameters, using ***termcap*** syntax.  But *termcap* can only represent **2** parameters.  To do this in ***terminfo*** the developer should have done something like this:

```
tputs(tparm("\E[48;2;%p1%d;%p2%d;%p3%dm", _r, _g, _b), 1, DoAddChar);
```

One of ncurses' [bug-fixes](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-ncurses/2017-07/msg00056.html) during 2017 made that slice of code obsolete:

```
    + improve _nc_tparm_analyze, using that to extend the checks made by
      tic for reporting inconsistencies between the expected number of
      parameters for a capability and the actual.
```

GNU screen, by the way, is a *termcap* application, and mixing in *terminfo* calls (such as **`tparm`**, which is not a [*termcap*](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_termcap.3x.html) feature) makes it less portable than one might wish.  For formatting output, *termcap* provides only [**`tgoto`**](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_termcap.3x.html#h3-FORMATTING-CAPABILITIES), which uses exactly two parameters.

Followup: the suggested improvement was applied [2018/11/18](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/screen.git/commit/?id=98d688cfb257f526dcadbb6cc6a20573d63af450), after some discussion in this [bug report](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?54989).

Comment: thanks for the help! glad to see this is working again (based on 30 seconds of testing at least)